# Read attribute from XML file

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read XML attributes from XML file. I want to echo baadNavn.

```php
                <?php
                $url = "https://xml.websejler.dk/da/baad/1234";
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
                print_r($xml);
                echo $xml[baad][baadNavn];
                ?>
```

What do I wrong?

---

Print_r gives me:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [baad] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baadId] => 1234 [maalerId] => 32217 [baadNavn] => Ongo Bongo [baadStatus] => dhkolbaad [dhKlasseStatus] => skrogmedspeciel [nation] => DEN [sejlnummer] => 46 [byggerNavn] => Granada Yacht [byggeAar] => 1978 [maaleDato] => 1991-05-13T00:00:00 [stabgodk] => 0 [skrogMaterialeId] => 1003 [materiale] => GRP [opfolg] => 0 [fysisk] => 1 [baadtypeId] => 146 [rigsejlId] => 28158 [skrogId] => 17214 [specielId] => 79368 ) [certifikat] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [certifikatId] => 1234 [gyldigt] => 0 ) ) [baadtype] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baadtypeId] => 146 [baadtypeNavn] => GRANADA 31 [baadStatus] => dhkolbaad [dhKlasseStatus] => skrogmedspeciel [dhBeregnes] => 1 [bem] => Granada 311 har samme skrog som Granada 31. De første ca. 35 var med blykøl (KC 0,96) - senere kommer det med jernkøl (KC 1,17) [skrogId] => 17214 [specielId] => 79368 ) ) [rigsejl] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [RigsejlId] => 28158 [E] => 3.27 [P] => 11.14 [HB] => 0.15 [MGM] => 2.10 [MGU] => 1.21 [Tmax] => 12.10 [LP] => 5.23 [FSP] => 0.08 [SPL] => 0.00 [J] => 3.49 [TPS] => 0.00 [JHW] => 0.00 [ISP] => 12.38 [SL] => 0.00 [SLU] => 0.00 [SLE] => 0.00 [SF] => 0.00 [SMG] => 0.00 [SFA] => 0.00 [SMGA] => 0.00 [PropelId] => 2 [propel] => Fri foldepropel med 2-3 blade (2) [RF] => 0 [MF] => 0 [HF] => 0 ) ) [skrog] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [SkrogId] => 17214 [Gmax] => 6.42 [SGmax] => 5.59 [FBSB] => 0.93 [FBBB] => 0.94 [SBmax] => 5.73 [UDFSB] => 0.26 [UDFBB] => 0.26 [OF] => 1.17 [OA] => 0.00 [UDHBmax] => 0.00 [UDHmax] => 0.00 [STF] => 1.11 [AF] => 0.00 ) ) [speciel] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [SpecielId] => 79368 [Bmax] => 3.05 [LOA] => 9.38 [D] => 4.17 [K] => 1.80 [KC] => 0.96 [KFId] => 1 [KF] => Normal [KontrolVejet] => 0 [KontrolMaalt] => 0 [KontrolKrenget] => 0 ) ) [ejer] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [personId] => 53371 [klubId] => 318 [klubNavn] => Aarhus Sejlklub [arrangor] => 1 ) ) [offentligmaaler] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [personId] => 32217 [aktiv] => 0 [maaHentePersonlister] => 0 [offentlig] => 0 [sejlmager] => 0 [maalerbem] => [navn] => Niels Agerskov ) ) [beregning] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baadId] => 1234 [status] => beregnet [oprettetTid] => 2019-05-10T12:15:32.637 [beregnetTid] => 2019-05-10T12:16:31.447 [beregnetOATid] => 43595.5115 [beskedSendes] => 1 ) ) ) )
```

XML files contains:

```xml
<websejler>
<baad baadId="1234" maalerId="32217" baadNavn="Ongo Bongo" baadStatus="dhkolbaad" dhKlasseStatus="skrogmedspeciel" nation="DEN" sejlnummer="46" byggerNavn="Granada Yacht" byggeAar="1978" maaleDato="1991-05-13T00:00:00" stabgodk="0" skrogMaterialeId="1003" materiale="GRP" opfolg="0" fysisk="1" baadtypeId="146" rigsejlId="28158" skrogId="17214" specielId="79368">
<certifikat certifikatId="1234" gyldigt="0"/>
<baadtype baadtypeId="146" baadtypeNavn="GRANADA 31" baadStatus="dhkolbaad" dhKlasseStatus="skrogmedspeciel" dhBeregnes="1" bem="Granada 311 har samme skrog som Granada 31. De første ca. 35 var med blykøl (KC 0,96) - senere kommer det med jernkøl (KC 1,17)" skrogId="17214" specielId="79368"/>
<rigsejl RigsejlId="28158" E="3.27" P="11.14" HB="0.15" MGM="2.10" MGU="1.21" Tmax="12.10" LP="5.23" FSP="0.08" SPL="0.00" J="3.49" TPS="0.00" JHW="0.00" ISP="12.38" SL="0.00" SLU="0.00" SLE="0.00" SF="0.00" SMG="0.00" SFA="0.00" SMGA="0.00" PropelId="2" propel="Fri foldepropel med 2-3 blade (2)" RF="0" MF="0" HF="0"/>
<skrog SkrogId="17214" Gmax="6.42" SGmax="5.59" FBSB="0.93" FBBB="0.94" SBmax="5.73" UDFSB="0.26" UDFBB="0.26" OF="1.17" OA="0.00" UDHBmax="0.00" UDHmax="0.00" STF="1.11" AF="0.00"/>
<speciel SpecielId="79368" Bmax="3.05" LOA="9.38" D="4.17" K="1.80" KC="0.96" KFId="1" KF="Normal" KontrolVejet="0" KontrolMaalt="0" KontrolKrenget="0"/>
<ejer personId="53371" klubId="318" klubNavn="Aarhus Sejlklub" arrangor="1"/>
<offentligmaaler personId="32217" aktiv="0" maaHentePersonlister="0" offentlig="0" sejlmager="0" maalerbem="" navn="Niels Agerskov"/>
<beregning baadId="1234" status="beregnet" oprettetTid="2019-05-10T12:15:32.637" beregnetTid="2019-05-10T12:16:31.447" beregnetOATid="43595.5115" beskedSendes="1"/>
</baad>
</websejler>
```

I expect to get "Ongo Bongo" as result.

Comment: Use object access: `$xml->baad->baadNavn`.  When asking a question like this though, you should really provide the source XML.  Or at least a relevant sample of it.

Comment: echo $xml->baad->baadNavn; doesn't work. Can you try with my code and return an example that works with my code?

Comment: Put your XML in the body of the question.  Also show what you expect the result to be.

Comment: The print_r gives me:
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [baad] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [baadId] => 1234 [maalerId] => 32217 [baadNavn] => Ongo Bongo [baadStatus] => dhkolbaad [dhKlasseStatus] => skrogmedspeciel [nation] => DEN [sejlnummer] => 46 ........
I expect "Ongo Bongo" as result.

Comment: XML file contains:
<websejler>
<baad baadId="1234" maalerId="32217" baadNavn="Ongo Bongo" baadStatus="dhkolbaad" dhKlasseStatus="skrogmedspeciel" nation="DEN" sejlnummer="46" byggerNavn="Granada Yacht" byggeAar="1978" maaleDato="1991-05-13T00:00:00" stabgodk="0" skrogMaterialeId="1003" materiale="GRP" opfolg="0" fysisk="1" baadtypeId="146" rigsejlId="28158" skrogId="17214" specielId="79368">
</baad>
</websejler>

Comment: Please put information like this _in the question_, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$url = "https://xml.websejler.dk/da/baad/1234";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo (string) $xml->baad->attributes()['baadNavn']; // Ongo Bongo
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, this works fine. But what if if want to get baadtype->attributes()['baadtypeNavn'] = GRANADA 31. I try with echo (string) $xml->baadtype->attributes()['baadtypeNavn']; but this doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: `baadtype` is a child node of `baad`, you need to follow the node tree to the one you need: `echo (string) $xml->baad->baadtype->attributes()['baadtypeNavn'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attributes() function on the node to get it's attributes:

```
$xml_str = '<xml>
    <node>
        <someTag cp="c2">content</someTag>
    </node>
</xml>';
$res = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);

$items = $res->xpath("//someTag");
var_dump((string) $items[0]->attributes()->cp);
```

The returned element is an SimpleXMLElement, so in order to use it I converted it to string (using the (string) cast).